# zend framework slug creator for utf8 character

Tags: zend-framework, slug

I want to create a SEO friendly url, so after a few research, i come up with creating slug and do something with the router. However, it seems that the slug creator around internet only support english alphabet character. So, i need a better slug creator for my vietnamese alphabet.

Anyone got a plugin, or a suggestion for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend an existing Slugifier to normalize the vietnamese characters.

From a [similar post in the Django context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072623/739373):

> A simple version for you case would be:
>
> ```
> vietnamese_map = {
>     ord(u'ư'): 'u',
>     ord(u'ơ'): 'o',
>     ord(u'á'): 'a',
>     ord(u'n'): 'n',
>     ord(u'h'): 'h',
>     ord(u'ữ'): 'u',
>     ord(u'n'): 'n',
>     ord(u'g'): 'g',
>     ord(u'v'): 'v',
>     ord(u'i'): 'i',
>     ord(u'ê'): 'e',
>     ord(u'n'): 'n',
>     ord(u'k'): 'k',
>     ord(u'ẹ'): 'e',
>     ord(u'o'): 'o',
> }
> ```
>
> And then you can call:
>
> ```
> print u"những-viên-kẹo".translate(vietnamese_map) To get:
>
> u"nhung-vien-keo"
> ```

But of course you'll need to write that in PHP.

If you don't want to extend the builtin slugifier, Boris Guery's `Bgy_Filter_Slugify` works well for me:

https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Filter/Slugify.php

You could also extract the slugification code used by WordPress, if that still isn't robust enough for you.

**EDIT:**

WordPress code [may already handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371799/739373) the conversion of accented characters into their latin equivalent.

[Here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L607) for example is their `remove_accents` function.