# Django: Slug in Vietnamese working not correctly

Tags: python, django, slug

I begin to develop website online store using Django framework. I have faced with problem that I want to change the name in Vietnamese "những-viên-kẹo" to "nhung-vien-keo". I have read this article: 
[Django: Slug in Vietnamese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605041/django-slug-in-vietnamese)

and I do something on model.py like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,help_text = 'Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255, help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,  help_text = 'Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:  
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_category', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug })
```

But when I type "những-viên-kẹo" in the Name field of Admin page, the slug field appear "nhng-vien-ko". I don't know something wrong. 
And when I run a test with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
vietnamese_map = {
    ord(u'ư'): 'u',
    ord(u'ơ'): 'o',
    ord(u'á'): 'a',
    ord(u'n'): 'n',
    ord(u'h'): 'h',
    ord(u'ữ'): 'u',
    ord(u'n'): 'n',
    ord(u'g'): 'g',
    ord(u'v'): 'v',
    ord(u'i'): 'i',
    ord(u'ê'): 'e',
    ord(u'n'): 'n',
    ord(u'k'): 'k',
    ord(u'ẹ'): 'e',
    ord(u'o'): 'o',
}

print unicode("những-viên-kẹo").translate(vietnamese_map)
```

It work correctly, and return "nhung-vien-keo"

[EDIT]

I have try this on my form.py

```
class CategoryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        exclude = ()

    def clean_slug(self):
        slug = self.cleaned_data['slug']
        vietnamese_map = {
            ord(u'ư'): 'u',
            ord(u'ơ'): 'o',
            ord(u'á'): 'a',
            ord(u'n'): 'n',
            ord(u'h'): 'h',
            ord(u'ữ'): 'u',
            ord(u'n'): 'n',
            ord(u'g'): 'g',
            ord(u'v'): 'v',
            ord(u'i'): 'i',
            ord(u'ê'): 'e',
            ord(u'n'): 'n',
            ord(u'k'): 'k',
            ord(u'ẹ'): 'e',
            ord(u'o'): 'o',
        }
        slug = slugify(unicode(slug).translate(vietnamese_map))
        return slug
```

And in admin.py

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = CategoryAdminForm
    # sets up values for how admin site lists categories
    list_display = ('name', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_display_links = ('name',)
    list_per_page = 20
    ordering = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name', 'description', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_description']
    exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)
    # sets up slug to be generated from category name
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

But it still not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. At first, I define a map that contain key value paired. Key is a character Vietnamese in UTF-8. Then I use this to convert some special character to relevant in English:

```html
def vi_slug(data):
    vietnamese_map = {
        ord(u'o'): 'o', ord(u'ò'): 'o', ord(u'ó'): 'o', ord(u'ỏ'): 'o', ord(u'õ'): 'o', ord(u'ọ'): 'o',
        ord(u'ơ'): 'o', ord(u'ờ'): 'o', ord(u'ớ'): 'o', ord(u'ở'): 'o', ord(u'ỡ'): 'o', ord(u'ợ'): 'o',
        ord(u'ô'): 'o', ord(u'ồ'): 'o', ord(u'ố'): 'o', ord(u'ổ'): 'o', ord(u'ỗ'): 'o', ord(u'ộ'): 'o',

        ord(u'à'): 'a', ord(u'á'): 'a', ord(u'á'): 'a', ord(u'ả'): 'a', ord(u'ã'): 'a', ord(u'ạ'): 'a',
        ord(u'ă'): 'a', ord(u'ắ'): 'a', ord(u'ằ'): 'a', ord(u'ẳ'): 'a', ord(u'ẵ'): 'a', ord(u'ạ'): 'a',
        ord(u'â'): 'a', ord(u'ầ'): 'a', ord(u'ấ'): 'a', ord(u'ậ'): 'a', ord(u'ẫ'): 'a', ord(u'ẩ'): 'a',

        ord(u'đ'): 'd', ord(u'Đ'): 'd',

        ord(u'è'): 'e', ord(u'é'): 'e', ord(u'ẻ'): 'e', ord(u'ẽ'): 'e', ord(u'ẹ'): 'e',
        ord(u'ê'): 'e', ord(u'ề'): 'e', ord(u'ế'): 'e', ord(u'ể'): 'e', ord(u'ễ'): 'e', ord(u'ệ'): 'e',

        ord(u'ì'): 'i', ord(u'í'): 'i', ord(u'ỉ'): 'i', ord(u'ĩ'): 'i', ord(u'ị'): 'i',
        ord(u'ư'): 'u', ord(u'ừ'): 'u', ord(u'ứ'): 'u', ord(u'ử'): 'ữ', ord(u'ữ'): 'u', ord(u'ự'): 'u',
        ord(u'ý'): 'y', ord(u'ỳ'): 'y', ord(u'ỷ'): 'y', ord(u'ỹ'): 'y', ord(u'ỵ'): 'y',
    }
    slug = slugify(unicode(data).translate(vietnamese_map))
    return slug
```

Then you should override the save method for changing slug before it will be saved.
Note: the slug field has change to TextField.

```html
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.parent_category is None:
            try:
                parent_category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.parent_category)
                parent_category.numberChild += 1
                parent_category.save()

                if self.slug == "":
                    self.slug = vi_slug(self.name)
                else:
                    self.slug = vi_slug(self.slug)
            except:
                pass
        super(Category, self).save()
```

Hope this can help you less comsuming time for solving the same problem.